# EDSDK Camera seems "Locked" with Message "Recording... Remaining Images"

Tags: c#, edsdk, canon-sdk

I'm remote controlling a Canon EOS 1000D using EDSDK 3.6.1 and C#.

Sometimes after (successfully) taking a photo and downloading the images (RAW+L) the camera seems to "hang". Live view doesn't work any more and/or the camera seems unresponsive via EDSDK. When I try to turn off the camera its display shows:

> Recording...
>   Remaining images :2

This normally means: the camera is busy writing data to the card. 
However it seems the camera endlessly writes data in these cases.

Do I need to tell the camera that I finished downloading the images or something similar?

However, it seems to work when remote controlling the camera w/o card.

*UPDATE 1:*

Just had this issue without any card in the camera.

*UPDATE 2:*

The `EdsDownloadComplete` command will be called after each download. However, I get still get this error randomly: sometimes after the 2nd or 3rd photo/download, sometimes later. Quite strange... :-(

`EdsRelease` returns always 0, meaning there are no further reference counters on this file/object.

Is there probably a way to check the download state before taking a photo/starting live view and cancel all remaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that there is something happening in parallel when downloading the images and that's never good with the Canon SDK. I think if you put a lock around the DownloadReady event handling it should work.

*This answer was written by Johannes Bildstein as a comment and works fine for me.*

Answer (score 1):

This message means that the camera thinks that the images haven't been saved yet. i.e. the taken images are still in the buffer. This only happens if you have set SaveTo to Host (possibly also with Both), because then the images aren't written to the memory card.

You have to call EdsDownloadComplete (with the file pointer from the DownloadReady object event) after you have downloaded the file. Or if you don't want to download it, call EdsDownloadCancel (again, with the file pointer).

Comment: Hi Johannes, I'll try that after christmas. Thank you very much and merry christmas to you! :-)

Comment: The `EdsDownloadComplete` command will be called after download. However, I get still get this error randomly: sometimes after the 2nd or 3rd photo/download, sometimes later. Quite strange... :-(

`EdsRelease` returns always 0, meaning there are no further reference counters on this file/object.

Comment: @Spock, is there any chance you are trying to do things in parallel? You could also compare your code to this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp

Comment: I'm using your `EDSDKLib`... ;-)

Comment: @Spock, oh I see, gotta fix something then. Does it happen with the example projects? and if so, does it also happen if you only take one picture type (i.e. only RAW and not RAW+L)

Comment: I could reproduce it with the sample project:

Save photos to computer, take a few photos, after the 4th photo (this amount may differ) downloading hangs and the camera tells "Recording... Remaining images..." when I try to shut it down.

*Note:* I needed to modify your code to use `MainCamera.TakePhoto()` for my 1000D is too old to understand `SendCommand(CameraCommand.PressShutterButton, (int)ShutterButton.Completely)`.

I'm using a Canon EOS 1000D.

Comment: your guess with the picture type seems correct: when I shoot in RAW or L-JPEG only, everything seems fine. When I use both, the camera hangs after a few shots.

That's a least a work-around for me. :-)

Comment: @Spock, good to know, thanks for the infos. I'm guessing that there is something happening in parallel when downloading the images and that's never good with the Canon SDK. I think if you put a lock around the DownloadReady event handling it should work. It's not elegant but it should do the trick. I'll have a closer look at it in the library a little later.

Comment: Putting a lock around the code in my `DownloadReady` method indeed seems to work. Make an answer from your comment and I'll accept it! Thanks a lot, Johannes!